# VBA Crashing When There are around 730 Rows of References

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA codes which calculate the number of "X" of items by column and row, run well with references around 400 rows (around 22 items due to merged cells). However, when I increased the references up to around 730 rows (36 items), they crashed every time. They sometimes keep running without feedback/reaction, or sometimes pop error message saying Runtime error 2147417848 (80010108) "Select method of Range class failed".

I checked all my codes, and I do activate the worksheets before selecting ranges in them.
I've checked if the loops are endless or not, but the two do-loops do have ends at the last line of two worksheets (row 116 and 726).
I use 8GB ram and Intel Core i5-6500 @ 3.2GHz to run Excel 2013 on Windows 8.1 Enterprise, which should be enough for the codes.

Can anyone please tell me what's going wrong?

Edit:
After revision the codes below work fine now. Thanks for all the tips!
One question is:
How to make them more concise?
Both range and the added numbers enumerate at the same time. I tried to save the numbers in a variant array und use double for-loops, but either the numbers are added in one cell, or the range is populated with the same number...

```
Dim ZSF_rng As Range
ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 2).Value + Korruption_schlecht_number
ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 3).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 3).Value + Korruption_mitte_number
ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 4).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 4).Value + Korruption_gut_number
ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 5).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 5).Value + Menschenrecht_gut_number
ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 6).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 6).Value + Menschenrecht_mitte_number
ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 7).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 7).Value + Menschenrecht_schlecht_number
ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 8).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 8).Value + Arbeitssicherheit_gut_number
ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 9).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 9).Value + Arbeitssicherheit_mitte_number
ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 10).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 10).Value + Arbeitssicherheit_schlecht_number
ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 11).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 11).Value + Umweltschutz_gut_number
ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 12).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 12).Value + Umweltschutz_mitte_number
ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 13).Value = ZSF_rng.Offset(0, 13).Value + Umweltschutz_schlecht_number
```

Comment: You may have a look onto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: As outlined in the link posted by Shrotter - you should consider re-working your code to remove all the Select/Activate steps: in 99% of cases there's no need to select/activate anything in order to work with it.

Comment: You can use [COUNTIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countif) to count how often 'X' occurs. You should also replace all of your `Set rBlank =...rBlank.ClearContents` blocks with a function (the body of which could simply be `rng.Value = rng.Value + number`) since there are 12 such (inefficient) blocks in your existing code.